# Ribbon Cable Pin Assignment

Tags: pins, fabrication, continuity

Preface: I am complete novice at electronics and this is my first project.

I am trying to connect two PCB together with a 10pin ribbon cable. The ribbon cables I made (and bought) are all showing continuity between pin1 on on end and pin 2 on the opposite end of the cable. Should not pin1 match (and have continuity) to pin1 on the opposite end of the ribbon cable?

I am assuming from my limited knowledge that pin1 on one PCB would have to match to pin1 on the other. Right now because of the pin assignments they are not and therefore no signal is going through <?>.

Am I right in my assumptions, or completely wrong? Any pointers or suggestions?

Edit:

Link to the cables I bought for testing purposes - which still show pin1 continuity to p2 at the other end.

https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B06XDPHP6M?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

I don't have data sheets - cables were bought off of amazon.

Pictures in onedrive link show cable attached to DMM and not attached, as well as the pins I'm trying to connect to from the two PCB.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtgyNyFMbMA-luY7fHT6yttss24yHQ?e=TxqwVh

Am I even using the right cables? If someone has a link to something I should be using (if I'm not, that would be great). Thanks agaain!

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us a link to the datasheet for the cables you bought, and tell us whether the cables have connectors on them.

Comment: It sounds like you're using ribbon cables that are assembled with IDC connectors pressed on.  The phenomenon you are describing sounds like the cable has been assembled incorrectly -- this is why we are asking you to _edit your question_ with pictures of your cable if you built them, or with datasheets.

Comment: @TimWescott added images and amazon link. thank you.

Comment: This might be relevant, depending on how your connectors are arranged. It’s very easy to get an accidental 180 degree flip with these type of connectors. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492952/why-isnt-this-ribbon-cable-between-two-board-to-board-connectors-working

Comment: @user3746283 in your pic 'cable 1' you have your test leads plugged into pin-1 on both ends of the ribbon cable and, as expected, your multimeter reads continuity. In 'pcbs' one of the board has its header rotated by 180°, but this shouldn't cause trouble. I don't see any problem with the cable or the pcbs.

Answer (score 0):

Get a continuity meter and ohm it out, (place one probe on pin one and then probe the other pins until the meter indicates continuity)

Most DMMs come with a continuity meter these days